# Continuous integration always fails with VERR_VMX_NO_VMX

Tags: continuous-integration, vagrant, virtualbox, travis-ci, packer

I am developing an application for a class, and use Packer, Vagrant, and VirtualBox to build and deploy my application.

For a fresh install, the (dev's view) build steps looks like:

1. Build VirtualBox images with `packer build {...}.json`
2. Provision and run VirtualBox images with `vagrant up`
3. Hey! Web application!

The repository is here: https://github.com/HenryFBP/2019-team-07f-mirror

Long story short, I'm trying to add continuous integration to test each commit so I (and my team members) don't have to.

I've so far tried both AppVeyor and Travis, but each time the build stops with VirtualBox reporting `VERR_VMX_NO_VMX`, and it just looks like whatever machine I'm running `VBoxManage` on doesn't have VT-x enabled.

Short of re-writing my provisioning steps in Docker or doing self-hosting, how can I get a CI provider that gives me this VT-x feature?

Should I actually just tell Vagrant to use Docker instead of VirtualBox?

Should I modify my `Vagrantfile` to use Docker? Should I switch CI providers? Should I use a self-hosted option like Concourse?

I'm hesitant to try another CI provider because I don't want to just rediscover that they don't have VT-x.

Error from Travis: https://travis-ci.org/HenryFBP/2019-team-07f-mirror/builds/507577619

Error from Appveyor: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/HenryFBP/2019-team-07f-mirror/build/job/piku3n5eav1o1ioe

Thanks!

## EDIT #1

I am using Jenkins and it rocks! It's self-hosted and super great. I can run whatever I want on bare-metal. It's the solution for me and took literally one afternoon to set up.

Comment: Check if your CI SaaS supports _nested virtualization_. It's usually documented.

Comment: That's a good idea! Thanks!